# What are the reason of kuber pod failing with Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak

recently got this error in the pod I usually run, don't think I changed anything related to this pod.

pod logs:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/04/25 09:58:39 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2022/04/25 09:58:39 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are doing but the final error message is permission denied for nginx.  So there is a problem with the user privs for nginx process on the containing folder /var/cache/nginx

Comment: @Vorsprung yeah I see, its weird because I did no permission changes, do you know is there a way to change pod permissions?

Comment: yes there is but it's not as simple as that

Comment: @Vorsprung can you link resource that contains info on how to manage pod permissions?